# Grayscale vs Color FFT

Tags: c#, fft

The following code converts a color image to Grayscale and then computes its FFT:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap source = pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap;

        Bitmap gray = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(source);

        Complex[,] cpxImage = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(gray);

        Complex[,] fftCpxImage = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxImage);

        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxImage = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxImage);

        Bitmap mag = FourierPlot.FftMagnitudePlot(shiftedFftCpxImage, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Bitmap phase = FourierPlot.FftPhasePlot(shiftedFftCpxImage, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        pictureBox2.Image = gray;

        pictureBox3.Image =  mag;

        pictureBox4.Image = phase;
    }
```

The following code splits a color image into three channels computes their FFTs and merges them together to form an RGB image of the FFT.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap source = pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap;

        int [,,] array3d = ImageDataConverter.ToInteger3d(source);

        int[,] red = ArrayTools<int>.Split(array3d, 0);
        int[,] green = ArrayTools<int>.Split(array3d, 1);
        int[,] blue = ArrayTools<int>.Split(array3d, 2);

        Complex [,] cpxRed = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(red);
        Complex [,] cpxGreen = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(green);
        Complex [,] cpxBlue = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(blue);

        Complex[,] fftCpxRed = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxRed);
        Complex[,] fftCpxGreen = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxGreen);
        Complex[,] fftCpxBlue = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxBlue);

        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxRed = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxRed);
        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxGreen = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxGreen);
        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxBlue = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxBlue);

        int[,] fftRed = ImageDataConverter.ToIntegerMagnitude(shiftedFftCpxRed);
        int[,] fftGreen = ImageDataConverter.ToIntegerMagnitude(shiftedFftCpxGreen);
        int[,] fftBlue = ImageDataConverter.ToIntegerMagnitude(shiftedFftCpxBlue);

        int [,,] dest = ArrayTools<int>.Merge(fftRed, fftGreen, fftBlue);

        Bitmap mag = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap3d(dest, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Grayscale.SetPalette(mag);

        pictureBox3.Image = mag;
    }
```

**Output**

[image][image]

In the first case, the outcome is very good, and as expected. In the second case, the output is totally black.

**One more test:** if I take only one channel, again the output is cool:

```
        ... ... ...

        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxRed = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxRed);
        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxGreen = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxGreen);
        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxBlue = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxBlue);

        Bitmap mag = FourierPlot.FftMagnitudePlot(shiftedFftCpxRed, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Bitmap phase = FourierPlot.FftPhasePlot(shiftedFftCpxRed, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        pictureBox2.Image = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap2d(red, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        pictureBox3.Image = mag;
        pictureBox4.Image = phase;

        ... ... ...
```

[image]

I think there is a problem in

```
    public static int[,] ToIntegerMagnitude(Complex[,] image)
    {
        int Width = image.GetLength(0);
        int Height = image.GetLength(1);

        int[,] integer = new int[Width, Height];


        for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
            {
                integer[i, j] = ((int)image[i, j].Magnitude);
            }
        }

        return integer;
    }
```

This is only taking the magnitude part and hence losing data in the process.

Any suggestions?

.

**Relevant Source Code**

```
public static class FourierPlot
{
    public static Bitmap FftMagnitudePlot(Complex[,] fftImage, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        int[,] FourierMagnitudeNormalizedInteger = FourierNormalizer.Normalize(fftImage, NormalizeType.Magnitude);

        Bitmap color = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap2d(FourierMagnitudeNormalizedInteger, pixelFormat);

        Grayscale.SetPalette(color);

        return color;
    }

    public static Bitmap FftPhasePlot(Complex[,] fftImage, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        int[,] FourierPhaseNormalizedInteger = FourierNormalizer.Normalize(fftImage, NormalizeType.Phase);

        Bitmap color = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap2d(FourierPhaseNormalizedInteger, pixelFormat);

        Grayscale.SetPalette(color);

        return color;
    }
}

public partial class FourierNormalizer
{
    public static int[,] Normalize(Complex[,] Output, NormalizeType normalizeType)
    {
        int Width = Output.GetLength(0);
        int Height = Output.GetLength(1);

        double[,] FourierDouble = new double[Width, Height];
        double[,] FourierLogDouble = new double[Width, Height];
        int[,] FourierNormalizedInteger = new int[Width, Height];

        double max = 0;

        if (normalizeType == NormalizeType.Magnitude)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
                {
                    FourierDouble[i, j] = Output[i, j].Magnitude;
                    FourierLogDouble[i, j] = (double)Math.Log(1 + FourierDouble[i, j]);
                }
            }

            max = FourierLogDouble[0, 0];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
                {
                    FourierDouble[i, j] = Output[i, j].Phase;
                    FourierLogDouble[i, j] = (double)Math.Log(1 + Math.Abs(FourierDouble[i, j]));
                }
            }

            FourierLogDouble[0, 0] = 0;
            max = FourierLogDouble[1, 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
            {
                if (FourierLogDouble[i, j] > max)
                {
                    max = FourierLogDouble[i, j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
            {
                FourierLogDouble[i, j] = FourierLogDouble[i, j] / max;
            }
        }

        if (normalizeType == NormalizeType.Magnitude)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
                {
                    FourierNormalizedInteger[i, j] = (int)(2000 * FourierLogDouble[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= Height - 1; j++)
                {
                    FourierNormalizedInteger[i, j] = (int)(255 * FourierLogDouble[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }

        return FourierNormalizedInteger;
    }
}

    public static Bitmap ToBitmap3d(int[, ,] image, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        int Width = image.GetLength(1);
        int Height = image.GetLength(2);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, pixelFormat);

        BitmapLocker locker = new BitmapLocker(bmp);
        locker.Lock();

        int [,] red = ArrayTools<int>.Split(image, 0);
        int [,] green = ArrayTools<int>.Split(image, 1);
        int [,] blue = ArrayTools<int>.Split(image, 2);

        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                int r = red[x,y];
                int g = green[x,y];
                int b = blue[x,y];

                Color clr = Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);

                locker.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
            }
        }

        locker.Unlock();

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: You probably don't want to convert to integer the magnitude like that. You'll need to scale things first. Can't you use `FourierPlot.FftMagnitudePlot()` to convert each channel result to an integer bitmap, then combine those bitmaps?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Yes, I can. But, why doesn't this specific code work? And, how can I make this work?

Comment: `FourierPlot.FftMagnitudePlot` seems to apply a logarithmic stretching of the input values. You don't do this in your conversion to integer, it is likely that all values are just too low in brightness to be seen.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, code for `FftMagnitudePlot` is included.

Comment: Indeed. I would pass the 3 channels through `FourierNormalizer.Normalize`, then combine them into a color bitmap.

Comment: Can you post the code for `ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap3d`?

Comment: @mnistic, added.

Comment: If you are using the `Locker` class from my previous answer (the latest) then you have to set the palette before using `locker.SetPixel()`, so change `Bitmap mag = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap3d(dest, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Grayscale.SetPalette(mag);` to `Grayscale.SetPalette(mag); Bitmap mag = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap3d(dest, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);`

Comment: Also, it's not going to work unless the color matches exactly. Is there a reason you want your output image to be 8-bit indexed?

Comment: @mnistic, no there is no reason. It's just convenient. 1-channel is convenient to convert to 8-bit color/grayscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image]

This comment solved my problem.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap source = (Bitmap)(pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap).Clone();

        int[, ,] array3d = ImageDataConverter.ToInteger3d(source);

        int[,] red = ArrayTools<int>.Split(array3d, 0);
        int[,] green = ArrayTools<int>.Split(array3d, 1);
        int[,] blue = ArrayTools<int>.Split(array3d, 2);

        Complex[,] cpxRed = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(red);
        Complex[,] cpxGreen = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(green);
        Complex[,] cpxBlue = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(blue);

        Complex[,] fftCpxRed = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxRed);
        Complex[,] fftCpxGreen = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxGreen);
        Complex[,] fftCpxBlue = FourierTransform.ForwardFFT(cpxBlue);

        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxRed = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxRed);
        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxGreen = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxGreen);
        Complex[,] shiftedFftCpxBlue = FourierShifter.ShiftFft(fftCpxBlue);

        int[,] normRed = FourierNormalizer.Normalize(shiftedFftCpxRed, NormalizeType.Magnitude);
        int[,] normGreen = FourierNormalizer.Normalize(shiftedFftCpxGreen, NormalizeType.Magnitude);
        int[,] normBlue = FourierNormalizer.Normalize(shiftedFftCpxBlue, NormalizeType.Magnitude);

        Bitmap mag = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap3d(normRed, normGreen, normBlue, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        //Grayscale.SetPalette(mag);
        //Bitmap mag = FourierPlot.FftMagnitudePlot(shiftedFftCpxRed, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Bitmap phase = FourierPlot.FftPhasePlot(shiftedFftCpxRed, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        pictureBox2.Image = mag;
        pictureBox3.Image = mag;
        pictureBox4.Image = phase;
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :)